# How to add alphanumeric values in a speardsheet if they are comma separated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

Suppose, we have cells as below:

```
Cell  Value       Legend
==========================
 A1    1,A      // A = 1
 A2    2,AA     // AA = 2
 A3    3,L      // L = -1
 A4    4,N      // N = 0
```

I want the total to be calculated separately in other cells as:

```
A5  = SUM(1, 2, 3, 4)          = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
A6  = SUM(1*A, 2*AA, 3*L, 4*N) = 1 + 4 - 3 + 0 = 2
```

Considering it may require separate functions in App Script, I tried to use SPLIT and SUM them, but it's not accepting the values. I asked a related question: [How to pass multiple comma separated values in a cell to a custom function?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162188/how-to-pass-multiple-comma-separated-values-in-a-cell-to-a-custom-function)

However, being a novice in spreadsheet, I am not sure if my approach is correct.
How to add alphanumeric values separately as stated above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a small lookup table (legend) and then for the first sum try something like

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4, "[0-9-.]+")+0)))
```

[image]

and for the last

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(A1:A4, "[0-9-.]+")*vlookup(regexextract(A1:A4, "[^,]+$"),D1:E4, 2, 0 ))))
```

[image]

Comment: @iammilind: added an iferror() into the functions. Updated my answer.

Comment: Somehow this first equation doesn't recognize the negative & decimal values; e.g. if I pass `-1,A` instead of `1,A`, the result remains the same for "7". It should be rather "5". Similar thing for the decimal values.

Comment: What decimal sign do you use: . or ,  ?

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: I use dot "." only for decimlas; i.e. instead of `1,A`, it will be `-0.5,A` or "0.5,L" and so on. Comma is exclusively for separating alphanumerics.

Comment: @iammilind: updated my answer.